# How to show $g:A\to f(A)$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, functions

> Let $ (X,\tau) $ and $(Y,\tau^*)$ topological spaces, $A\in \tau$ and
>   $f:X\to Y$ is open function. Show $g:A \to f(A)$ which is generated by
>   restricting of function $f$, is open.

Let $g:X\to Y$  is open and $B\subset A \in \tau$ .  is $f(B)\in\tau^*?$

since $B\in\tau$ and $g:X\to Y$  is open. we know $g(B)\in \tau^* $.

It seems easy but couldnt continue

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 6 questions during last 2 or 3 days. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks. I already know that. it is not important anymore because I asked all my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is that if $B\in\tau$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $g(B)$ is open. But you have to show that if $B$ is **open in $A$**, then $g(B)$ is **open in $g(A)$**.

Here's a counterexample which shows that the restriction of an open function to a non-open $A$ need not be open.
The projection $\pi_X$ of a product $X\times Y$ to its factor $X$ is always open. Take $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and $\pi_X$ the projection onto the first coordinate. Let $A=[-1,1)×\{0\}\cup \{0\}×\Bbb R$. Then $\{0\}×(0,1)$ is **open in $A$**, but its image $\{0\}$ is not **open in $\pi_X(A)=[-1,1)$**.
However, if you restrict $π_X$ to the saturation $A':=π_X^{-1}(π_X(A))$, then this will be open as a map $A'\to[-1,1)$, but still not open as a map $A'\to\Bbb R$.

This shows how crucial it is to say in which space a set is open. If you want the restriction of an open $g:X\to Y$ to be open as a map $g|_A:A\to Y$, you need openness of $A$ somewhere.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the restriction of an open map $f: X\to Y$ to a subset $A\subset X$ always open w.r.t the respective subspace topologies on $A$ and $f(A)$?

Comment: @MatthiasValvekens: No, it's not, see my counterexample.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. I see the obvious flaw in my back-of-the-envelope "proof" now. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to use that, if $A\subseteq X$ is *open* (i.e., $\in\tau$), then  $B\subseteq A$ is open in $X$ iff it is open in $A$ w.r.t. the subspace topology $\tau|_A:=\{G\cap A\mid G\in\tau\}$.

So, if $B$ is open in $A$ (i.e. $B\in\tau|_A$) then $B$ is also open in $X$, hence $g(B)=f(B)$ is open ($\in\tau^*$). $\quad\quad  $ `-QED-`